# Tengo un proyecto con Laravel versión 4.2 ¿Cómo actualizo a la ultima versión?

Tags: laravel

Estoy intentando instalar la version de laravel 4.2
pero me salta este error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y por otro lado en la documentación de laravel para su instalación me pide
*****"Asegúrese de colocar el ~/.composer/vendor/bin directorio en su RUTA para que el laravelejecutable se encuentre cuando ejecute el laravel comando en su terminal."***** no entiendo donde es que encuentro el archivo que menciona y donde es que debo ubicarlo, ya que ese directorio que me indican no lo encuentro en ningún lado.

Comment: Tal vez sea en "variables de entorno" de windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

estuve trabajando con una version laravel version 5.8 , te digo que primero vas a necesitar obtener  la version de php compatible con tu version de laravel y la version de composer 1.10(en mi caso) para que cuando hagas el composer install te reconozca todas las dependencias. (vendor es tu carpeta de dependencias se crea cuando haces composer install)

Comment: Gracias, ahí voy a revisar esto que me indicas. te agradezco